# Authentication token in SOAP header

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

i have .asmx webservice that is secured. if the authentication is successful then an authentication token is issued. however, i am making some jQuery calls and I wanted to know how to send a authentication token as a part of the SOAP header.

the following is the .NET equivalent code.

```
svc = new SecuredWebService.SecuredWebService();
svc.SoapHeader = new SecuredWebService.SecuredWebServiceHeader();
svc.SoapHeader.Username = "test";
svc.SoapHeader.Password = "test";

Guid g;
string token = svc.AuthenticateUser();

if (Guid.TryParse(token, out g) == true)
{
    //    auth.AuthenticatedToken = token;
    svc.SoapHeader.AuthenticatedToken = token;
    serverlbl.Text = (token);
}

serverlbl.Text += ":";
serverlbl.Text += svc.HelloWorld();
```

the authentication token is required for each web request.

Comment: What type of authentication are you using on your service? You can user [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) attribute of jQuery ajax call to populate your custom headers.

Comment: There's a jQuery SOAP plugin which supports authentication, http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/, might be up your alley.

Comment: I think beforeSend might work but I am not sure how to construct the soap header

Comment: The jquery plugin also looks like a good option but I think that would mean a lot of code rewrie

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What would you use in jQuery to call an ASMX web service that was not secured with a token?

Comment: like this     var data = { 'UserID': "" + UserID + "", 'CaseID': "" + CaseID + "" };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Service.asmx/GetReferenceGrid",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            RefGrid = response;
        }
    });